# ipconfig does not show me my Ethernet NAS's true IP

Tags: networking, ip, nas

I have a Synology NAS that's connected to my computer via Ethernet. When I run `ipconfig`, the IP address listed as the "Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address" for the Ethernet connection isn't right.

[image: ipconfig]

I have to use Synology's Assistant app, which shows me the correct one.

[image: Synology Assistant]

Where's that second IP coming from, and how can I get access to it outside of the Assistant?

Comment: you run ipconfig on your local machine and you compare this with the IP of the NAS/server/zeppelin ?? also: don't use DHCP on your synology NAS: give it a fixed IP, much handier e.g. for bookmarking to the admin pages and web pages etc...

Comment: Are those the results of running ipconfig on your pc?

Comment: I should add that I don't know much about networking, which is why I'm asking this question. It's not clear to me exactly what happens when you connect one device directly to another with an Ethernet cable.

Comment: Yes, both ipconfig and the Synology Assistant are running on my local PC.

Comment: Can you post the full results of ipconfig on your pc?

Comment: You are confusing your local IP address of your laptop (which runs windows so you can use ipconfig to get the IP of THAT local machine) with the IP address of the server (NAS) (which runs a custom linux version) (and which IP you see in synology assistant)

Comment: OK, I see. So where's the "router" for this configuration? Is it running in software on the Windows machine? How can I find out the IP address of my NAS from Windows, aside from using the Assistant?

Comment: I suspect you have somewhere a machine that gives you an IP address: the DHCP server: probably the router in your closet "the little box that connects you to the internet". I think it does not assign you a correct IP address.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. For internet, I use wireless, and only my laptop is connected to that. The NAS and the laptop are directly connected to each other with Ethernet. There's two networks involved. If I take my laptop off the wireless network, the same thing will still happen.

Comment: what is the IP adress of your WIFI adapter? So not your Ethernet adapter? :: if you do not have a DHCP server assigning a unique address to your NAS and your laptop you have to set them fixed.

Comment: 192.168.1.149 -- different subnet. Nothing to do with the Ethernet issue I'm wondering about, I think.

Comment: Then I would set FIXED on your NAS: 192.168.1.50 and give your laptop ethernet adapter 192.168.1.49

Comment: But the NAS isn't on the 192.168.1.1 network, it's on whatever network Windows establishes when you connect one machine directly to another with an Ethernet cable. (Hence the 169.254...) I don't think the NAS even has access to the internet through my computer. And anyway, I'm not trying to fix anything, everything works correctly, I'm just wondering about the discrepancy I see between the IP in ipconfig and the IP provided by the Synology Assistant.

Comment: They both point to "unassigned" and no the NAS has no access to the internet through your computer.

Answer (score 1):

*"ipconfig does not show me my Ethernet NAS's true IP"*

**device 1** (has 2 network adapters): ipconfig is run on your Windows laptop and is a windows command. When no fixed IP address is set on your network adapter and you do not receive one from a DHCP server such as the Wifi Adapter on your laptop it gives you 169.254.... for the fixed lan adapter.

**device 2**: The NAS runs Linux and via Synology Assistant it does a lookup and retrieves the IP address of the NAS network adapater. Since that is also not connected to a DHCP server and also has no fixed IP address it also gets a 169.254... address. (which is shown in synology assistant)

It is highly recommended to give both a fixed IP address.